# How to draw a line from first mouseclick to second with easel.js

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I tried to create eventlisteners drawing to a `stage.mouseY` `stage.MouseX` coordinates, but no matter where I click the line is the exact same straight down the middle.

Here's my code

```
   Ext.onReady( function(){
  var g;




  canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
  var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

function draw(a){
var mousex = stage.mouseX;
var mousey = stage.mouseY;
a.lineTo(mousex, mousey);
}

g = new createjs.Graphics();

g.setStrokeStyle(1);
g.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0));
g.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,0,0));
stage.addEventListener('click', draw(g));
g.lineTo(0,50);

var s = new createjs.Shape(g);
    s.x = 100;
    s.y = 100;

stage.addChild(s);
stage.update();


});
```

My long term goal is to create user created polygons that are selectable/highlightable is this a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your problem is:

```
stage.addEventListener('click', draw(g));
```

It will immediately execute the `draw` function with parameter `g`. It won't wait for the click. The problem is that with parentheses following the function name, the function will be executed immediately. What you need is to have a function reference to the draw function. You can have that by using an anonymous function

```
stage.addEventListener('click', function() {draw(g); });
```